# Overclocking tools in Linux

Tags: linux, hardware, x86, system-information

I am trying to overclock my machine. All the changes are made on the BIOS level, but then one needs to check all the temperatures, voltages, etc and test the stability of the overclock. Most tutorials (if not all) are written for Windows. What would be Linux alternatives for:

**CPU-Z**: to display all the CPU information, including Core Speed, Core Voltage, current multiplier, etc.

**HWMonitor**: check fan speed and core temperatures

**Prime95**: stress testing with results validation

Also I would like to be able to monitor VTT and NB voltages (see [a short explanation of all voltages](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/Understanding-All-Voltage-Configurations-from-the-Motherboard/995)) for Intel processors (I have a Q9450) - I haven't actually found a Windows program that does it yet.

Comment: prime95 => gimps @ http://mersenne.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CPU-Z I can't really say (`/proc/cpuinfo` doesn't give core speed, multiplier etc...).

For hardware monitoring the `sensors` command (part of the `lm_sensors` package) should work; it doesn't have a GUI per se, however.

Finally, the [`stresslinux`](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/) distro has many stress-testing utilities.

> stresslinux makes use of some utitlities available on the net like: stress, cpuburn, hddtemp, lm_sensors ...
>
> stresslinux is dedicated to users who want to test their system(s) entirely on high load and monitoring the health.
>
> Stresslinux is for people (system builders, overclockers) who want to test their hardware under high load and monitor stability and thermal environment.

Answer (score 5):

google search the **highlighted**  names for more infomation

### CPU-Z alternatives  (CPU information)

1. **CPU-G**  (Simple)
2. [**i-nex**](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/04/i-nex-advanced-cpu-z-hardware-utility-for-linux.html) (Advanced)

   [installation](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/cpuz-alternatives-inex-cpug-for-ubuntu.html) tutorial

### **HWMonitor** alternatives (temperatures & fans speeds)

1. **Psensor** (Easy)
2. **Xsensors** (Simple)  [GUI for `lm-sensors`] use [`watch -n 1 -d sensors`]

for Desktop integration use **gatotray** or the [Panel applet] **sensors**

### Prime95 alternatives  (Stress testing)

1. **MPrime** (command line) [linux version of Prime95]
2. **system stability tester** (Easy) [CPU]
3. **unigine  benchmarks** (Awesomely Easy) [GPU]
4. **Phoronix Test Suite** |Stress-run| (expert) [all hardware]
5. **Breakin stress-test** (Expert) [bootable OS] [all hardware]

### System & hardware information

1. **HardInfo**  (easy) [System profiler and benchmark]
2. **kinfocenter** (Simple)
3. **sysinfo** (Basic)
4. **lshw-gtk** (Advanced) or [`sudo lshw -short`]

install with `sudo apt-get install (name here)`

### terminal commands & utilities

**stress testing** 

`stress`  &  `stress-ng
cpuburn
stressapptest`

**System** information commands

`sudo dmidecode --type processor`      [ for help google **dmidecode Details**]

```
sudo cpufreq-info
```

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

```
inxi -xSCs
```

```
hwinfo --short
```

Comment: you can help by adding appropriate links to numbered &  highlight  names, because i can't

Answer (score 4):

For stress testing I recommend using [SETI@home](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/) for two reasons:

1. Great stress testing
2. Your PC helps science

For changing voltages, use [linux-PHC](http://www.linux-phc.org/) (CLI)

For monitoring temperatures, use [lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/) (CLI)

For Ubuntu/Debian (as root):

```
apt-get install lm-sensors
yes | sensors-detect
/etc/init.d/module-init-tools start
```

Then type:

```
sensors
```

It should show you temperatures.